# Upgrading to macOS Sierra breaks PHP/MYSQL configuration

Tags: php, mysql, macos, config, macos-sierra

So I recently upgraded to macOS Sierra (Beta) and it broke my PHP/MySQL config... no real surprise there but... what's weird is that some quick terminal commands show me that PHP and MySQL are both up and running! For example... PHP:

```
myusername@myworkstation  /private/etc/apache2/other  php -v
PHP 5.6.24 (cli) (built: Aug  9 2016 16:05:05)
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
```

So, I decided to run

```
apachectl configtest
```

And herein lies the problem:

```
httpd: Syntax error on line 537 of /private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf: Syntax error on line 8 of /private/etc/apache2/other/+entropy-php.conf: Cannot load /usr/local/php5/libphp5.so into server: dlopen(/usr/local/php5/libphp5.so, 10): Symbol not found: _environ\n  Referenced from: /usr/local/php5/libphp5.so\n  Expected in: /usr/sbin/httpd\n
```

So the problem is that the OS can't find or can't load PHP... any ideas how to resolve this? Seems like an incorrect path but wondering if anything changed on the OS side that caused this? Not much in the OS Sierra bandwidth concerning this issue. Hoping to connect with other dev's that have run into this issue as of late or someone who might better understand how to get back up and running again.

Thanks in advance for any help and in the meantime, I'll continue my fix attempts in hopes this can be quickly resolved.

Comment: Using the version that ships with the OS is going to leave you with one that's wickedly out of date. Why not use [Homebrew](http://brew.sh) to grab a more recent version, one you have full control over?

Comment: Assuming you mean the PHP version... I'll give that a try, I have homebrew installed. Will report back. Thanks @tadman

Comment: Yeah, the PHP version. The OS comes bundled with older versions of PHP that are updated on a very conservative basis. If you want the latest, which is recommended for anyone doing PHP development, you need a tool like Homebrew to install it for you. Same goes for Python, Ruby, Node.js and so on.

Comment: @tadman while the homebrew solution works for my personal workstation (home office), I have another office where I can't even install homebrew, node, npm, (anything command line) etc due to strict firewall rules. I'm going to leave this question open while I agree with you that using the "out of box" version isn't what I would recommend either, unfortunately, I have a workspace where it is my only option (to use the OS version). Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Do you get different results on a clean OS install vs. an upgrade in-place?

Comment: I'm unable to even try a clean OS install @ work, I could roll back to El Capitan, but that would be my only option there. All of the software purchasing and procurement is out of my hands so requesting an image of Sierra Beta (Which my job technically doesn't even support Mac) would be an uphill battle to say the least. Unfortunately I've been battling sickness for the past week so, I'll try some things when I can get back in the office and start looking for workarounds. I'm hoping when Mac releases a stable version of Sierra that this will clear itself up, but that's a tall order.

Comment: You can always try and boot up a new install in a VM like VMWare Fusion or VirtualBox if that's an option. This is a peculiar problem you're seeing here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a similar issue. Seems like sierra overwrites the config files. I got php working by uncommenting the php loadmodule line in httpd.conf. My websites are working again but all my vhost stuff seems to be gone. I will recreate the configs and add to this if it helped.

Comment: Could you show us your vhost configuration if you manage to make things work ?
I have an error with apache saying : Cannot load libexec/apache2/mod_authn_default.so and when i try one of my local website, i have the "It Works" message :(

Comment: I'm going to try to uncomment the php settings in httpd.config, thanks for that nugget sixstring!

Comment: @tomzi your path may be looking for your username specific profile, if you get the "It's Working" at "localhost", then the path to your user directory needs to be changed.

Comment: @sixstring after re-uncommenting the httpd.config files, then editing my httpd-userdir.conf file to uncomment the call to php there, everything is back to normal. My "localhost" returns "It Works" and my bookmarked local WordPress development sites (in my user directory) are back up and running. Thanks for the help sixstring.

Comment: Glad I had the answer!

Answer (score 4):

I noticed this today when I realized that the macOS Sierra update messed up my localhost.

After doing some digging, it appears that the config files were overwritten. I've discovered that the devs were nice enough to save your previous config files you had in place in a backup file before they overwrote the default configs in /etc/apache2/.

For the your original httpd.conf before the update, look for a file named "httpd.conf~pre-update"

Inside /etc/apache2/extra/, for all your original files, look for the files with the "~previous" at the end of the name.

The .bak files are now backups of the new macOS Sierra apache configs (so I think if you had backups with the .bak, those were overwritten as well, but not 100% sure).

At this point, I'm not sure of the ramifications of setting your original files back as the defaults, but when I restored my original config files, everything magically worked again. Hope this helps anybody else with this issue.

Comment: That is a truly helpful answer. Im sure an OS update for apple is just around the corner.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue for days. I got php working again by uncommenting the LoadModule php5_module libexec/apache2/libphp5.so line in httpd.conf. I hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

There are lots of config files that have been replaced - so you need to go through them all and reset your entire configuration.  The good guys at Apple have really helped out by ensuring every single configuration option is saved at least somewhere on your drive!

Next, you will find your MySQL isn't working, it's changed versions and the databases are no longer where you left them.  But don't panic a simple boot into the recovery option, copy the databases from the previous location (if you can find them) to the new location (if you have any idea where that is) is all that is required.  But then you may also need to locate the my.cnf - it's gone!  I couldn't find the old one, and the new one doesn't tell me where the old one has gone.

But don't go changing the location of the databases - it needs to be in that 'data' folder.  Any attempt to move it will result it ghostly apparitions of your data appearing on screens all over the office.

Finally we are back to php and the extensions.  Yes - there are a couple missing, mine were mcrypt and memcache, but don't panic, you can find copies in hidden in a folder called 'extensions', but finding that folder will involve you solving a number of strategy games along the way - good luck.

BTW - if you are reading this before you found the 'extensions' folder, it doesn't really matter because those extensions don't work with the installed version of php, so it didn't really matter if you couldn't find them.  Just download the source, compile, make, make install, do that twice, maybe three times for good measure, and it still won't work.

I hope this has really helped somebody - I'm sure glad to have it all worked out now.

And don't you think somebody should take responsibility for this?

If only I had stayed on El Capitan!